# How to implement IIR Band-Pass Filter for an input audio in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, filter, signal-processing

How do I implement an IIR bandpass filter in my current android code? I have an android app which could record audio (frequency actually) and save it in a .wav file.

I have managed to find a IIR Filter Library online but I am not sure how to implement it into my code.

https://github.com/ddf/Minim/blob/master/src/ddf/minim/effects/BandPass.java
https://github.com/DASAR/Minim-Android/blob/master/src/ddf/minim/effects/IIRFilter.java

I am supposed to add the 18k-20k bandpass filter to the code before outputting the received sound signal into a .wav file.

My current code

```
package com.example.audio;


import ddf.minim.effects.*;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.varma.samples.audiorecorder.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RecorderActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;// 44100; //18000
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO; //AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    private static final int PLAY_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO; //AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
    private static final int FREQUENCY_LEFT  = 2000; //Original:18000 (16 Dec)
    private static final int FREQUENCY_RIGHT  = 2000; //Original:18000 (16 Dec)
    private static final int AMPLITUDE_LEFT = 1;
    private static final int AMPLITUDE_RIGHT = 1;
    private static final int DURATION_SECOND = 10;
    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    private static final float SWEEP_RANGE = 1000.0f;

    String store;
    private AudioRecord recorder = null;
    private int bufferSize = 0;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    double time;
    float[] buffer1;
    float[] buffer2;
    byte[] byteBuffer1;
    byte[] byteBuffer2;
    byte[] byteBufferFinal;
    int bufferIndex;
    short x;
    short y;
    AudioTrack audioTrack;

    Button btnPlay, btnStart, btnStop;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setButtonHandlers();
        enableButtons(false);

        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

        buffer1 = new float[(int) (DURATION_SECOND * SAMPLE_RATE)];
        buffer2 = new float[(int) (DURATION_SECOND * SAMPLE_RATE)];

        float f1 = 0.0f, f2 = 0.0f;

        for (int sample = 0, step = 0; sample < buffer1.length; sample++) {
            time = sample / (SAMPLE_RATE * 1.0);
            //f1 = (float)(FREQUENCY_LEFT + ((sample / (buffer1.length * 1.0)) * SWEEP_RANGE)); // frequency sweep
            //f2 = (float)(FREQUENCY_RIGHT + ((sample / (buffer1.length * 1.0)) * SWEEP_RANGE)); // frequency sweep
            f1 = FREQUENCY_LEFT; // static frequency
            f2 = FREQUENCY_RIGHT; // static frequency
            buffer1[sample] = (float) (AMPLITUDE_LEFT * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f1 * time));
            buffer2[sample] = (float) (AMPLITUDE_RIGHT * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f2 * time));
        }

        byteBuffer1 = new byte[buffer1.length * 2]; // two bytes per audio
                                                    // frame, 16 bits

        for (int i = 0, bufferIndex = 0; i < byteBuffer1.length; i++) {
            x = (short) (buffer1[bufferIndex++] * 32767.0); // [2^16 - 1]/2 =
                                                            // 32767.0
            byteBuffer1[i] = (byte) x; // low byte
            byteBuffer1[++i] = (byte) (x >>> 8); // high byte
        }

        byteBuffer2 = new byte[buffer2.length * 2];

        for (int j = 0, bufferIndex = 0; j < byteBuffer2.length; j++) {
            y = (short) (buffer2[bufferIndex++] * 32767.0);
            byteBuffer2[j] = (byte) y; // low byte
            byteBuffer2[++j] = (byte) (y >>> 8); // high byte

        }

        byteBufferFinal = new byte[byteBuffer1.length * 2];
        // LL RR LL RR LL RR
        for (int k = 0, index = 0; index < byteBufferFinal.length - 4; k = k + 2) {
            byteBufferFinal[index] = byteBuffer1[k]; // LEFT
                                                        // {0,1/4,5/8,9/12,13;...}
            byteBufferFinal[index + 1] = byteBuffer1[k + 1];
            index = index + 2;

            byteBufferFinal[index] = byteBuffer2[k]; // RIGHT
                                                        // {2,3/6,7/10,11;...}
            byteBufferFinal[index + 1] = byteBuffer2[k + 1];
            index = index + 2;
        }



        try {
            FileOutputStream ss = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER + "/source.txt");
            ss.write(byteBufferFinal);
            ss.flush();
            ss.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe){
            Log.e("IO Error","Write source error.");
        }
    }

    private void setButtonHandlers() {
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(startClick);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(stopClick);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)).setOnClickListener(playClick);
    }

    private void enableButton(int id, boolean isEnable) {
        ((Button) findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
    }

    private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
        enableButton(R.id.btnStart, !isRecording);
        enableButton(R.id.btnStop, isRecording);
        enableButton(R.id.btnPlay, isRecording);
    }

    private String getFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{filepath}, null, null);

        store = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Audio"          
            + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV;

        return store;
    }

    private String getTempFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        File tempFile = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

        if (tempFile.exists())
            tempFile.delete();

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
    }

    private void startRecording() {

        //BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100);
    /*  BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(50,2,SAMPLE_RATE);
        int [] freqR = {FREQUENCY_RIGHT};
        int [] freqL = {FREQUENCY_LEFT};

        float[] testL = shortToFloat(freqR);
        float [] testR = shortToFloat(freqL);
        bandpass.process(testL,testR);
        bandpass.printCoeff();
        */
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

        /*
         * AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
         * (int) RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
         * AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
         */

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                (int) SAMPLE_RATE, PLAY_CHANNELS,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, byteBufferFinal.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

        audioTrack.write(byteBufferFinal, 0, byteBufferFinal.length);
        audioTrack.play();

        BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(50,2,SAMPLE_RATE);
        int [] freqR = {FREQUENCY_RIGHT};
        int [] freqL = {FREQUENCY_LEFT};

        float[] testL = shortToFloat(freqR);
        float [] testR = shortToFloat(freqL);
        bandpass.process(testL,testR);
        bandpass.printCoeff();

        audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE);
        recorder.startRecording();

        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    writeAudioDataToFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

        recordingThread.start();
    }

    double[][] deinterleaveData(double[] samples, int numChannels) {
        // assert(samples.length() % numChannels == 0);
        int numFrames = samples.length / numChannels;

        double[][] result = new double[numChannels][];
        for (int ch = 0; ch < numChannels; ch++) {
            result[ch] = new double[numFrames];
            for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
                result[ch][i] = samples[numChannels * i + ch];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }



    private void writeAudioDataToFile() throws IOException {
        int read = 0;
        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        String filename = getTempFilename();
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        FileOutputStream rs = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            rs = new FileOutputStream(getFilename().split(".wav")[0] + ".txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (null != os) {
            while (isRecording) {

                read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                    try {
                        os.write(data);
                        rs.write(data);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                os.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (null != recorder) {
            isRecording = false;

            audioTrack.flush();
            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.release();

            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;
        }

        copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename());
        deleteTempFile();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{getFilename()}, null, null);

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
    }

    private void deleteTempFile() {
        File file = new File(getTempFilename());
        file.delete();
    }

    private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, String outFilename) {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        long totalAudioLen = 0;
        long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
        long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
        int channels = 2;
        long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
            totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

            WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

            while (in.read(data) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void playWaveFile() {
        String filepath = store;
        Log.d("PLAYWAVEFILE", "I AM INSIDE");
        // define the buffer size for audio track
        int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        int bufferSize = 512;

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                (int) RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        int count = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                    fileInputStream);

            audioTrack.play();
            Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            while ((count = dataInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) > -1) {
                Log.d("PLAYWAVEFILE", "WHILE INSIDE");
                audioTrack.write(data, 0, count);


                //BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100); //Actual
                //BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(5000,2000,44100); //Test
                //int [] freqR = {FREQUENCY_RIGHT};
                //int [] freqL = {FREQUENCY_LEFT};

                //float[] testR = shortToFloat(freqR);
                //float [] testL = shortToFloat(freqL);
                //bandpass.process(testR,testL);


            //  BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100);


                //float bw = bandpass.getBandWidth();
                //float hello = bandpass.getBandWidth();
                //float freq = bandpass.frequency();

                //float[] test = {FREQUENCY_RIGHT,FREQUENCY_LEFT};

                //shortToFloat(test);
                //test [0] = FREQUENCY_RIGHT;
                //test [1] = FREQUENCY_LEFT;




                //bandpass.process(FREQUENCY_LEFT,FREQUENCY_RIGHT);

                //Log.d("MyApp","I am here");
                //Log.d("ADebugTag", "Valueeees: " + Float.toString(hello));
                //Log.d("Bandwidth: " , "Bandwidth: " + Float.toString(bw));
                //Log.d("Frequency: " , "Frequency is " + Float.toString(freq));
                //bandpass.setBandWidth(20);
                //bandpass.printCoeff();


            }

            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.release();
            dataInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void WriteWaveFileHeader(FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
            long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels, long byteRate)
            throws IOException {

        byte[] header = new byte[44];

        header[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[1] = 'I';
        header[2] = 'F';
        header[3] = 'F';
        header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
        header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[8] = 'W';
        header[9] = 'A';
        header[10] = 'V';
        header[11] = 'E';
        header[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
        header[13] = 'm';
        header[14] = 't';
        header[15] = ' ';
        header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
        header[17] = 0;
        header[18] = 0;
        header[19] = 0;
        header[20] = 1; // format = 1
        header[21] = 0;
        header[22] = (byte) channels;
        header[23] = 0;
        header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
        header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
        header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8); // block align
        header[33] = 0;
        header[34] = RECORDER_BPP; // bits per sample
        header[35] = 0;
        header[36] = 'd';
        header[37] = 'a';
        header[38] = 't';
        header[39] = 'a';
        header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
        header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

        out.write(header, 0, 44);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener startClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isRecording = true;
                    startRecording();
                }

            });

            recordThread.start();
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            btnPlay.setEnabled(false);

        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener stopClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    stopRecording();
                    enableButtons(false);
                    btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                    // stop();
                }

            }, 100);

        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener playClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            playWaveFile();
            btnPlay.setEnabled(true);

            String filepath = store;

            final String promptPlayRecord = "PlayWaveFile()\n" + filepath;

            SpannableStringBuilder biggerText = new SpannableStringBuilder(promptPlayRecord);
            biggerText.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.05f), 0, promptPlayRecord.length(), 0);
            Toast.makeText(RecorderActivity.this, biggerText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}
```

The method below is to convert my 16-bit integer to float since the library uses float

```
 /**
            * Convert int[] audio to 32 bit float format.
            * From [-32768,32768] to [-1,1] 
            * @param audio
            */
            private float[] shortToFloat(int[] audio) {
                Log.d("SHORTTOFLOAT","INSIDE SHORTTOFLOAT");
                float[] converted = new float[audio.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) {
                    // [-32768,32768] -> [-1,1]
                    converted[i] = audio[i] / 32768f; /* default range for Android PCM audio buffers) */

                }

                return converted;
            }
```

Trying to implement bandpass filter under "SaveRecording" Method

```
//BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100);
Since I am trying to implement a range of 18k to 20k, I input the above values to the bandpass filter.

BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(50,2,44100); (This is just to test if the frequency has any changes since 18k-20k is not within human range)
int [] freqR = {FREQUENCY_RIGHT};
int [] freqL = {FREQUENCY_LEFT};

float[] testL = shortToFloat(freqR);
float [] testR = shortToFloat(freqL);
bandpass.process(testL,testR);
bandpass.printCoeff();
```

Since I am recording in STEREO, I am using the
public final synchronized void process(float[] sigLeft, float[] sigRight) {} found in the IIRFilter.java class.

However, I am not hearing any differences even though I implemented the above method. What am I doing wrong? Could anyone advise/help me?

Thank You so much! Terribly new in this signal processing. Any tips/hints on how to progress is much appreciated!!!

***Updated***

Since I have to output the .wav file with the filtered sound signal, I thought the way to do it is to put the BandPass filter under the "StartRecording" method, however, it is not working. Why is it that I am doing wrong?

```
 private void startRecording() {

    int count = 0;

    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            (int) SAMPLE_RATE, PLAY_CHANNELS,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, byteBufferFinal.length,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);


        BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100);
        float[][] signals = deinterleaveData(byteToFloat(byteBufferFinal), 2);
        bandpass.process(signals[0], signals[1]);

        audioTrack.write(interleaveData(signals), 0, count, WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
        audioTrack.play();

        //audioTrack.write(byteBufferFinal, 0, byteBufferFinal.length); //Original


    audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE);
    recorder.startRecording();

    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                writeAudioDataToFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

    recordingThread.start();
}
```

**Updated (14 March 2016)**
This is the image of the output .wav file shown by Audacity:
[image: Output waveform in Audacity]

May I ask if it is considered filtered?
What are the characteristics that I should look out for to ensure that it is filtered correctly.

[image]

The above image produce by press the black triangle

[image]

The above image graph produced by the Analyse->Plot Specturm

[image]

What about this graph? Does it implement the bandpass filter successfully? Thank

Comment: Note that you should now have enough reputation to include images directly in your posts. You should use that instead of external image hosting sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with how you interface with the [Bandpass.java source](https://github.com/ddf/Minim/blob/master/src/ddf/minim/effects/BandPass.java), probably resulting from what appears to be a bit of a misconception: IIR filters do not process frequencies, but they rather process time-domain data samples (which may exhibit oscillatory behavior).

As such you have to provide those time domain samples as inputs to `Bandpass.process()`. Since you are reading raw bytes from file, you will need to convert those bytes to `float`. You could do this with:

```
/**
  * Convert byte[] raw audio to 16 bit int format.
  * @param rawdata
  */
private int[] byteToShort(byte[] rawdata) {
  int[] converted = new int[rawdata.length / 2];

  for (int i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) {
    // Wave file data are stored in little-endian order
    int lo = rawdata[2*i];
    int hi = rawdata[2*i+1];
    converted[i] = ((hi&0xFF)<<8) | (lo&0xFF);
  }
  return converted;
}
private float[] byteToFloat(byte[] audio) {
  return shortToFloat(byteToShort(audio));
}
```

Also for stereo wave files, you will get samples from the wave files which are interleaved. So you will also need to deinterleave the samples. This can be achieved in a similar fashion as you've done with `deinterleaveData`, except you will need a variant converting to `float[][]` instead of to `double[][]` since `Bandpass.process` expects `float` arrays.

You will of course also need to recombine the two channels back together after the filtering but before feeding the resulting filtered signals back to the `audioTrack`:

```
float[] interleaveData(float[][] data) {
  int numChannels = data.length;
  int numFrames   = data[0].length;

  float[] result = new float[numFrames*numChannels];
  for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
    for (int ch = 0; ch < numChannels; ch++) {
      result[numChannels * i + ch] = data[ch][i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

You should now have the required building blocks to filter your audio:

```
BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100);
while ((count = dataInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) > -1) {
  // decode and deinterleave stereo 16-bit per sample data
  float[][] signals = deinterleaveData(byteToFloat(data), 2);

  // filter data samples, updating the buffers with the filtered samples.
  bandpass.process(signals[0], signals[1]);

  // recombine signals for playback
  audioTrack.write(interleaveData(signals), 0, count, WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
}
```

*P.S.*: as a final note, you are currently reading all the wave file as data samples, header included. This will result in a short noisy burst at the beginning. To avoid this, you should skip the header.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help! Just a few more questions.

For the last section of the code, I added it inside the "PlayWaveFile" method. Am I on the right track?

Secondly, when I added the code 
float[][] signals = deinterleaveData(byteToFloat(data), 2);

Because deinterleaveData is returning double but the data pass to the method is a float, it is giving me this error.
The method deinterleaveData(double[], int) in the type RecorderActivity is not applicable for the arguments (float[], int)

Therefore, I changed the return value to of deinterleaveData to float.Is it ok? Will it affect anything?Ty

Comment: For 1) yes. For 2) That's why I said "as you've done with `deinterleaveData`, except you will need a variant converting to `float[][]`". You'll need to do a little bit more than just change the return type, i.e. also change the input type and the type of `result` in the implementation.

Comment: Greatly appreciated your advises and help! 

I have one last issue (I hope), when I clicked the "Play" button, I can hear the filtered sound audio (after applying the BandPass). But when I go to my .wav file it is the original sound. Since I have to output the .wav file of the filtered sound audio, I put the BandPass filter under the "StartRecording" but it is not working (stop working sometimes). I have updated my questions by including the amendments above. Thank You once again!!!!!

Comment: hi, would like to ask you one more question, why is it that when this code is being run (  audioTrack.write(interleaveData(signals), 0, count, WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);) it crashes the app. Checked the logcat and this is what it gave me

Comment: 12-22 16:09:27.842: E/AndroidRuntime(20754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-22 16:09:27.842: E/AndroidRuntime(20754): Process: com.varma.samples.audiorecorder, PID: 20754
12-22 16:09:27.842: E/AndroidRuntime(20754): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=128; index=128
12-22 16:09:27.842: E/AndroidRuntime(20754):  at com.example.audio17Dec.RecorderActivity.interleaveData(RecorderActivity.java:315)
12-22 16:09:27.842: E/AndroidRuntime(20754):  at com.example.audio17Dec.RecorderActivity.playWaveFile(RecorderActivity.java:538)

Really appreciate your help! Thank You so much!

Comment: my bad I had missed the `numChannels` factor in the allocation of the `result` array in `interleaveData`.

Comment: Hope you are able to assist. With the above code that you have provided, how do I detect that the audio is filtered? As in it is not be able to detect by human ear right? Do I have to use matlab?

Comment: Detecting that it is filtered could be done by ear if your input includes other audible frequencies (they should not be there in the output). But to detect that it correctly lets the 18-20kHz pass through, you'd indeed need a very good ear (or a dog willing to help) and a good speaker (they often  attenuate the signal above ~16-17kHz). Analyzing your output with Matlab or Audacity should show you the filtering effects more easily.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited my question and have uploaded an image of the waveform by using Audacity. Could you verify that if the waveform shows that the filter indeed take place? Thank You

Comment: Can't quite tell in the time domain. In Audacity, you can select some of the waveform and choose "Analyze -> Plot spectrum..." to see the frequency domain (from which you should be able to tell if your output is mostly within 18-20kHz). Alternatively, on the left side, clicking on the black triangle besides your "writeAudio" and selecting "Spectrogram" from the menu should give you a frequency vs. time spectrogram view (usually at a lower frequency resolution than the first option).

Comment: I have already uploaded both graphs based on your advises. How to tell if it is filtered within the 18-20khz? Please advise. Thank You so much!!! God Bless

Comment: If you bandpass within 18-20kHz, then that last plot should show much more intensity within that range. That graph shows that you still have a lot of the signal around 4-5kHz range, so it unfortunately looks like the bandpass didn't work too well.

Comment: Oh No!! Do you have any idea on how to resolve the issue? I implemented the code that you provided. But why is it not working. Oh shit

Comment: do I have to use the FFT library to implement the IIR filter for bandpass filter?

Comment: No you souldn't need an FFT library to implement an IIR filter. By the way that latest graph looks a lot more like some successful application of a bandpass with 18k-20kHz passband. There's still some out of band signal, but it's weaker that your main signal of interest. If you need more out of band attenuation you could pass your signal through multiple instances of IIR filter (in cascade).

Comment: Thanks:) Could you kindly explain how does the method interleaveData works? How does it combine the 2 channels back together? Thanks!

Comment: It produces a one-dimensional array of data by alternating the data samples from `numChannels` arrays of the same length. For example, if there are 2 channels `data[0]` and `data[1]`, the output would be the sequence `{data[0][0], data[1][0], data[0][1], data[1][1], data[0][2], data[1][2], data[0][3], data[1][3], ...}`

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. May I kindly ask what about the byteToShort method. What does the variables in  the for loop do? How does it work? Why do we have to convert byte raw audio to 16 bit int format first before converting to float? Thanks!! Have a pleasant day ahead!

Comment: Based on your `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` format selection, samples use 16 bits format. However the raw audio buffer is a sequence of bytes (8 bit). `byteToShort` combines pairs of bytes (one byte representing the least significant bits, and the other representing the most significant bits) into full samples. Then if you want floats you have to convert the integer value to float. Those two operations could be done in a single method, but I choose to reuse the `shortToFloat` you already had.

Comment: Thanks again!!!! I would like to ask basic qn. Not sure if you have any idea.  1. What is the buffer used for (eg: buffer1, buffer2, byteBuffer) 2. Why is the size of the buffer 44.1k (what's the relationship between buffer and sample rate) 3. Where else is the buffer used Thanks! Have a pleasant day!

Comment: 1) `buffer1` and `buffer2` in `onCreate` appear to be filled with floating point samples of test tones for the left & right channels. `byteBuffer1` & `byeBuffer2` are those test tones converted to a sequence of bytes with 16bits/sample encoding. 2) Size of the buffer is actually 441k samples for each channel. That's 10 second worth of data at 44100 samples/seconds (buffer size = duration * sample_rate). Why 10 seconds? Pretty arbitrary, long enough that a system could detect it, but not too long to drive your dog crazy or take huge amount of storage.

Comment: 3) For those same buffer as in (1), once those buffer are written to disk they are no longer needed. You can read & play those test tones (or some other files) with `playWaveFile` later.

Comment: but whats the relationship between sample rate and buffer size? Why is it that if the sample rate is 8k, the buffer size also is 8k? Likewise if the sample rate is 44.1k, then buffersize is also 44.1? ?_?

Comment: If you want **1second** of data, yes the buffer size is equal to the sample rate. As I mentioned, buffersize = duration * sample_rate. In general for audio applications if you make your buffer too big you have to wait forever for the buffer to fill up. If you make it too small you have to either feed (if you're playing sound) or get interrupted by data reception events (if you're recording) very frequently which can often have a negative impact on performance. The ideal choice of duration depends on the application, but 1second is often a good starting value (which you can then tune up/down).

Comment: so does it mean to say i have 10 secs of data so the buffer size will be 44100 (sample rate ) * 10 (secs) ? thats the buffer size? Thanks so much for explaining. Appreciated!

Comment: Any idea why this formula was used?  time = sample / (SAMPLE_RATE * 1.0); @@

Comment: It's evenly sampled data, so the time increases by a delta_time for each index which gives you a cumulative time equal to the sample number times that delta_time. In this case the sample number is the variable `sample`, the delta_time is the inverse of the sample rate (the more often you sample the smaller the time interval). So that would be time=sample*delta_time=sample*(1/SAMPLE_RATE)=sample/SAMPLE_RATE. But since `sample` and `SAMPLE_RATE` are integers, the `/` would be integer division which rounds the result down to an integer. `SAMPLE_RATE*1.0` converts that to the usual float division.

Comment: then what about this ? buffer1[sample] = (float)(amplitude1*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*f1*time)); what should it do? and what should the value be at buffer1????????????? T_T thanks for so being so patient and guiding me. I really appreciate it. God Bless

Comment: Btw, for this code BandPass bandpass = new BandPass(19000,2000,44100); the sample rate should be 44100 right (for both left + right) and not just left or right aka (22050)?

Comment: `buffer1[sample] = ...` computes a [sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave). values in `buffer1` will look like the graph on that wiki page. Sample rate 44100 is for each channel. Left would be sampled at 44100 samples/second, and right would also be sampled at 44100 samples/second. That would give you 44100*2 samples to handle for each second.

Comment: do you have any idea how to draw the sine wav in buffer1[sample] and buffer2[sample] ? @@ Please advise. THanks!

Comment: you mentioned that for stereo wave files, you will get samples from the wave files which are interleaved. So you will also need to deinterleave the samples. 
But what's the purpose of split the channels (deinterleave).
Also, after we deinterleave the left and right channel, what is the proces we must do before we combine (interleave) the channels together? I mean we could not possibly do nothing after splitting then combine the channels back again right? 

Thank You!

Comment: Is it we split the channel first (what's the reason behind), implement the filter, then combine back the channels again? (what's the reason?)

Comment: thanks for explaining to me and sorry to always bother you.

Comment: Left & right audio channels are generally independent streams of samples. The `Bandpass` filter you are using, like many other signal-processing algorithms, works (by design) on a single stream of data at a time, and doesn't know by itself how to extract that single stream of data from the buffer containing both left & right streams.You have to recombine them after because either you save it to wav and that's how wav are stored (interleaved samples), or you send it to audio output and that's what the audio API you are using expects.

Comment: You will of course also need to recombine the two channels back together after the filtering but before feeding the resulting filtered signals back to the audioTrack

Sorry, Could I check what do you mean by the above sentence?
What I interpreted was that , the filter is done after playback. then the channels will be recombined back after the playback. Am I right to say so?

Comment: Filtering would be done on an audio buffer (which could come from .wav file, or mic input). For stereo you have two channels, which means you process two audio buffers (and get 2 buffers at output of filter). After filtering is performed, you may want to either save the result to another .wav or play it to the speakers. The format expected of .wav file and playback interface (sent to speakers) is a single buffer. Since you have two buffers at the output of the filter, you need to merge them _before_ you can pass them to the playback interface as an audioTrack.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few problems...

1. The audio file you are trying to filter may not have much content that is noticeable to the ear in the bandpass range you are trying to filter.  Try filtering a much larger range to verify the filter works.  Try filtering most the song.
2. If you cannot get the above to work, then the filter is not being implemented properly.  You likely are not implementing the filter correctly.  For a really simple filter your could try Y[n] = X[n] - .5*X[n-1] which is a High Pass FIR filter with zero at 0 Hz.

Good Luck!