# Implementation of Bandpass Filter in Frequency Domain in Android

Tags: android, audio-processing

I get audio samples from microphone in Android which are to be filtered using *Bandpass Filter*. The filtering has to be done in frequency domain as steep cut-offs are required.

Can someone suggest ways of doing this filtering in Android?

I have tried designing a filter in time domain for the requirements. The order of the filter is extremely high but still the results are far from those obtained by filtering in frequency domain. This makes frequency domain filtering inevitable in this case.

Comment: I like the question, but it is a bit broad. Is your problem getting the raw audio data, the Fourier transform or the filter design? Did you already try something?

Comment: I get raw audio data from microphone. I could get the Fourier Transform using OpenCV but could not implement Bandpass filter after that. I have the implementation of this filter in Matlab which is freqDom[a:b] where the matrix freqDom is the fourier transform of the audio data and a, b are the indices corresponding to cut off frequencies.

Comment: Well, if you already have both the filter and signal in the frequency domain, the (time domain) filter convolution is now a simple element-wise multiplication. You can always pad the shorter signal or filter with zeros in the frequency domain to make them the same length. If that doesn't work, maybe look at the [Overlap-Add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement IIR Band-Pass Filter for an input audio in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319751/how-to-implement-iir-band-pass-filter-for-an-input-audio-in-android)

Comment: I have designed a time domain filter for the requirements but the order of the filter is extremely high. Even with that high order filter the results are far from those obtained by filtering in frequency domain. That is the reason why I am keen to filter by taking DFT of the signal.